# Awk - print the total files processed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

To print how many files were processed

```
awk 'FNR==1{count++}END{print count,"files processed"}' # Kinda lengthy
```

Is there a shorter solution available?

Also this fails if an empty files is passed? Any workarounds?

Comment: Use `c` instead of `count`? What do you expect?

Comment: @hek2mgl : any smaller solution is what i expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tiny improvement, if you use **GNU awk** and `BEGINFILE`, you will handle empty files:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME}' *txt empty /dev/null
```

**Output**

```
A.txt
B.txt
s.txt
empty
/dev/null
```

Comment: I take it Mark :) Thanyou